# Send message from Lambda to SQS in Go

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm looking to *send* a message to an SQS queue from a Lambda function written in Go, which in the AWS console I have configured so that the SQS queue is connected as a Destination.

[image: screenshot of console]

The code sample I've seen ([here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/go/sqs/SendMessage/SendMessage.go)) suggests I need to load a `config`, create a `client` and get a `queueURL` before issuing the message via a call to `SendMsg`. This approach works fine when running the code locally, but seems unnecessary within the Lambda given I'm connecting the SQS queue in the console. Do I need to tell my Lambda to find the queueURL when I've connected to it as a destination already?

As an aside, I tried this approach but was receiving the following error when running the code from within the Lambda. Invoking the code outside of a Lambda locally would find the queueURL without issue.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "operation error SQS: GetQueueUrl, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 2f725471-ec4e-5380-99ed-0f708c1fcfa4, AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue: ",
  "errorType": "OperationError"
}
```

This led me to look at the flip side, where I have a Lambda which is *consuming* from the queue and thereby has the SQS queue configured as a trigger. I simply need to iterate over the `sqsEvent.Records` without having to specify `config`, `client` or `queueURL` as I presume this is handled in the console behind the scenes, i.e.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func handler(ctx context.Context, sqsEvent events.SQSEvent) error {

    for _, message := range sqsEvent.Records {
        fmt.Printf("The message %s for event source %s = %s \n", message.MessageId, message.EventSource, message.Body)
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(handler)
}
```

Is there a way of sending a message to a queue from within the Lambda without having to find the `queueURL` first?

Comment: Do you know if you really need [destinations](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/)? What are you trying to achieve? If just sending a message to SQS, get rid of the Lambda destination and send a message directly using the example code. You don't need both in 95% of cases.

Comment: hmm interesting comment as perhaps then I misunderstand what destinations are used for. My use case is I have LambdaA which will run every N minutes and send lines of text to an SQS queue. LambdaB consumes from the queue and does something with the data. Would LambdaA not need to have the queue configured as a Destination?

Comment: No unless you want the output of an asynchronous Lambda invocation to go to the SQS queue. If you're triggering it every N minutes with EventBridge scheduling, your destination (SQS queue) wouldn't even get the data. You don't need it. Give Lambda A permission to send messages to the queue, use `SendMessage` to send messages and then set up Lambda B to be triggered by messages in the queue. No destinations needed.

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful to know! Do I still need the overhead of finding the `queueURL` and creating a `client` etc? I assume so, and if so any ideas on the error posted in the question?

Comment: I wouldn't call it an overhead, yes you need to create a client to talk to the SQS queue & you need the 'address' for it. The error message suggests it's not finding the queue, maybe double-check if you're looking in the right region. No worries.

Comment: Great, thanks for the clarity on the use of Destinations. I'm in the right region, I'll continue to troubleshoot that error, I imagine it's something simple that I'll come across. Appreciate the prompt replies, be well on your side of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have configured so that the SQS queue is connected as a Destination.

Sending a message doesn't need you to define a [destination](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/) per se - destinations are for passing asynchronous Lambda function invocation results. Basically - if you don't explicitly need them (and you know when you do), they won't be what you need.

Give your Lambda permission to send messages to the queue, & use `SendMessage` using the AWS SDK to send messages. No destinations needed.

> AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue

The error message suggests it's not finding the queue, maybe double-check if you're looking in the right region.

> I simply need to iterate over the sqsEvent.Records without having to specify config, client or queueURL as I presume this is handled in the console behind the scenes, i.e.

Yes, this is abstracted away - ultimately, your Lambda function is invoked by events and setting Amazon SQS as a trigger allows it to pass events to your function.

> Is there a way of sending a message to a queue from within the Lambda without having to find the queueURL first?

Let's rephrase it as - is there a way of sending a letter to someone without having to find their address? Of course not, as we need to know where the letter needs to go.

The same concept applies to SQS queues.